# WP / Display different posts on different parts of the website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a website with a content area and a sidebar (pretty common). I would like to offer my client the possibility to change the content in the content area (which is more or less static [company information, products...]), but also a news section in the sidebar, where they can post real news, almost like a blog section.
What is the best way to create such a scheme in wordpress?
I have thought about custom post types, shortcodes, dividing via different categories...

Thank you for your answers

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Static content area is normally done as wordpress pages.   Sidebar news is normally done using wordpress posts.  How it all displays depends on the wordpress theme template. One could have the template code display multiple pages on a home page.

Find a theme that is close to what you want and work with that.

Comment: This is built into WP already, you just need to move some things around. Use a page as the front page and then have a "News" page and set it as your posts page. Once you have that setup you can create widget to pull the posts into the sidebar.

Comment: thank you very much @JohanPretorius, works absolutely fine.